# delphi DBGrid display JOIN results

Tags: mysql, delphi, inner-join, dbgrid

I am working with BDS 2006,MySQL DB (MyDAC components used for connection) and i have a `DBGrid` component on my form which displays the records from my DB table.

Now i need to `JOIN` two tables and display the results in my `DBGrid`

The Resulting view that I should get is the result of the query

`SELECT e_salary.e_basic,e_details.e_name
  FROM e_details
  INNER JOIN e_salary
  ON e_details.e_id=e_salary.e_id;`

there is one more option to do it as I searched

`SELECT
    e_salary.e_basic,e_details.e_name
  FROM
    e_details, e_salary
  WHERE
    e_details.e_id=e_salary.e_id;`

e_details,e_salary are my two tables and e_id is my `PRIMARY KEY`

Presently I am having 2 `DBGrid` one is  for e_details and other for e_salary

Is it possible to have only 1 DBGrid displaying values from both the Tables? or I have to display 2 separate `DBGrid`?

If possible then how do I go about it

P.S.- there are more columns to be added in the view and both tables have same no of rows

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `DBGrid` displays a dataset data. The data may be result of some SQL query execution. `DBGrid`, `TDataSet` and `TDataSource` do not cary what was the SQL query. Single table `SELECT`, multi table `SELECT` with joins, stored procedure call or `SHOW` command. So, yes - you can use 1 DBGrid to display resultset of your `SELECT` joining 2 tables.
2. If both tables have the same number of rows, `e_id` is primary key for both tables, then why not to have single table, containing columns of both tables ? Also, if you will need to edit your dataset data, then there may be problems to update columns of both tables. And that may be one more argument to have single table.
3. Although you can use `WHERE e_details.e_id=e_salary.e_id` instead of `JOIN e_salary ON e_details.e_id=e_salary.e_id`. The JOIN is preferred, because DBMS gets your intent more explicitly and that is more readable for others.

Comment: having a single Table is not an option for me cause it will be too lengthy and both are having different functionality.And I m not providing an Edit option for the results(its just for the display purpose)

Comment: Ok, then (1) and (3) are actual for you. Although "too lengthy" and "different functionality" are not good arguments without details.

Comment: I have 2 DBGrid on other forms that display each of the Tables.
and combining both the tables will produce 30 odd columns which is hard for me to handle

Comment: You have few options to show only required columns - persistent fields, TField.Visible and persistent columns of TDBGrid.

Comment: ok I got it instead of assigning the `table datasource ` i have to assign the `query datasource` and there u get it.

Answer (score -1):

The DBgrid is probably not the component you need.
Give an eye to the TTreeView

http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/l/aa060603a.htm